# How to avoid overlaping corners on hard surface modeling?

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface, bevel

i´m trying to model this armor piece but im getting overlaping geometry in some corners using bevel modifier with bevel weight and subsurf.

[image: My geometry]

[image]

[image]

The only way i can manage to get rid of them is by adding edge loops but with that i can´t keep the roundness of my object.
[image]

Any help, advice or suggestions are much appreciated, thanks in advance.
If someone wants to take a look at the mesh in blender here´s a download link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wat10y8BVTwcdP_rpkes6gixkH9rZwMn

Comment: This happens all the time to me too. I hope you find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

i say it's the mirror and subdiv-suf modifiers, mess around with their positions in the stack. Mine seems fine though.